# No registered depth image in Fuerte

Tags: openni, ros-fuerte, openni-launch, openni-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using the /camera/depth_registered/image_rect message from a kinect using openni_launch, but he message is not sent in Fuerte. I tried setting depth_registration:

```
roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch depth_registration:=true
```

but still no registered depth image. In Electric everything works fine. Do I have to do something more to turn om the registered depth images in Fuerte?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46163/no-registered-depth-image-in-fuerte/) by [Ola Ringdahl](https://answers.ros.org/users/1011/ola-ringdahl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 328 on 2012-10-17

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Grega Pusnik](https://answers.ros.org/users/1849/grega-pusnik/) on 2012-10-18**:
Do you get any data on other published topics?

**Comment by [Ola Ringdahl](https://answers.ros.org/users/1011/ola-ringdahl/) on 2012-10-18**:
Yes, /camera/depth_registered/image_raw works for example. The RGB images are also published as they should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Now it works, but I have no idea why :-(

I re-installed openni and switched USB port for the camera. Now it works regardless of USB port used, so it could be that openni was broken somehow...

---

Originally posted by [Ola Ringdahl](https://answers.ros.org/users/1011/ola-ringdahl/) with karma: 328 on 2012-10-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1